# Authentication error with Microsoft Translation Service

Tags: translation, servicenow

We try to integrate servicenow dynamic translation with MS Translator but we are always getting code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."

ServiceNow Support tried themselves and got the same error.

API Key is correct and we currently use the free subscription from azure.

Comment: Hi Christoph. Please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one. Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: I get the same error. Not sure what the issue is